# Confusion about usage of 'new' for UI Widgets in QMainWindow constructor

Tags: c++, pointers, qt4, memory-management, widget

My coding practice using Qt can best be described as follows:

1. If the Widget is going to be actively used (e.g. A `QLineEdit` which provides text), I declare it in the header file and then initialise it in `MainWindow.cpp`.
   e.g. TextEditor.h:

`class TextEditor
{
//other code
private:
    QLineEdit edtFind;
};`

2.. If a widget is not going to be used (e.g. `QLabel`, `QWidget`), or it's part of a signal slot system (e.g. QPushButton), I declare and inialise it inside constructor using new.

-e.g.

```
TextEditor::TextEditor()
{
   //other code
   QWidget* searchPanel = new QWidget();
   edtFind = new QLineEdit("Enter Search Term");
   QPushButton* findButton = new QPushButton("Find");
   connect(findButton,SIGNAL(pressed()),this,SLOT(find()));

   ui->statusbar->addPermanentWidget(searchPanel);
}
```

My question is, am I using an efficient approach in point 2? Would it be better to not allocate memory from the heap?

Thanks.

Comment: Memory allocated using `new` is allocated on heap. So you are already doing that in 2nd point. And BTW the variables should be class member whenever they are _property_ of that class, and also the variables should have the narrowest lifetime and scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your approach is not efficient. You should use heap allocated objects when you actually need them:

- objects that have a longer lifetime
- using a forward declaration in order to avoid including a header file
- holding a reference to an object created elsewhere

Your approach is more complicated without any visible benefit. Heap is known to be slow, and allocating a large number of small objects is known to fragment it (this might not make a difference in your app but it's still a bad practice).

Answer (score 1):

While good advise for C++ in general, answer 1 is actually wrong for a big part in Qt: QObject (and with it all widgets, since QWidget derives from QObject). Rule there is to always allocate QObjects on the heap if they have a parent, because QObject features a parent-based garbage collection (when the topmost QObject-parent gets deleted, it will ask all its children to delete themselves recursively). The application may try to delete an object on the stack, which leads to a crash.

Note that some operations in Qt implicitly add or change the parent of a QObject as a side-effect (reparenting), such as adding a widget to a layout. However, this is usually documented in the API documentation. Since reparenting is very common with QWidgets, you should never put them on the stack. Other QObject-derived classes are safer, consult the API documentation in case of doubt.